# How can I customize my WCF service to use DataContractSurrogate only in one EndPoint?

Tags: .net, wcf, datacontractserializer

In my wcf service, I am interested in using DataContractSurrogate while exposing the ServiceContract in a particural EndPoint(e.g. WebHttpBinding).

1. How can I do it ? Implementing IEndpointBehavior?
2. In addition to that,do I need to implement IWsdlExportExtension?

Thanks,
Adil

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "Implementing a Surrogate" section at the MSDN page on Data Contract Surrogates.

You can find that page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733064.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e4e7b153-a213-4ee2-84fa-1d76838a58b5/

Comment: Link-only answers are more useful than no answer, but among other problems they are extremely vulnerable to link rot.